# Django queryset, calcular resta de dos numeros

Tags: python, python-3.x, django

Tengo el siguiente modelo:

```
class MyClass(models.model):
    usuario = models.Charfield(max_length=45)
    saldo_ini=models.DecimalField(decimal_places=1,max_digits=10, null=True)
    saldo_fin=models.DecimalField(decimal_places=1,max_digits=10, null=True)
```

En una vista quiero obtener el `usuario` y la resta de `saldo_fin - saldo_ini` usando un queryset. ¿Cómo hago esto?

Intenté con esto:

```
MyClass.objects.values('usuario').annotate(resta=float('saldo_fin') - float('saldo_ini'))
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Para estos casos puedes usar [expresiones F()](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/ref/models/expressions/#django.db.models.F) los cuales te permiten referenciar columnas de un modelo específico.

Por ejemplo, en el siguiente query estamos buscando libros cuya cantidad de `likes` sea mayor que la cantidad de páginas del mismo (tanto `likes` y `numero_paginas` son campo del modelo):

```
>>> Libro.objects.filter(likes__gt=F('numero_paginas'))
```

Para tu caso podrías usar:

```
>>> from django.db.models import F
>>> MyClass.objects.values('usuario').annotate(resta=F('hodometro_llegada') - F('hodometro_salida'))
```

Comment: Muchas gracias Cesar, era lo que necesitaba...